# What is the format of this m4 file?

Tags: file-format, m4

I found [this](https://github.com/dpisarenko/db-api/blob/songcontest1/now/schema.m4) m4 file in one of the open source projects.

```
changequote(«, »)dnl
include(«../defs.m4»)dnl
include(«tables.sql»)dnl
include(«functions.sql»)dnl
include(«triggers.sql»)dnl
include(«api.sql»)dnl
```

What is m4?

Is it the [GNU M4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisely so. M4 is a macro-processor.

This particular file includes five other files, which are, in turn, will be used as a list of instructions for processor. The resulting ouput will be sent to stdout.